# neo4j failing to reload - possible causes for failed store_lock permissions

Tags: nginx, flask, neo4j, permissions, py2neo

Until yesterday a site using neo4j + flask + nginx was working ok.
This morning I found error 500.

From the logs, it seems that the culprit is neo4j:

tail -100 /var/log/neo4j/neo4j.log

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Unable to obtain lock on store lock file: /usr/share/neo4j/data/databases/target_association.db/store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.StoreLocker.storeLockException(StoreLocker.java:94)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:86)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:40)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:433)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/store_lock (Permission denied)
```

This is for me cumbersome: it was working fine yesterday, all queries are GET, and the user permission of the db folder are owned by `testuser:staff`

**I have not changed persmissions: what could have happened?**

Testuser also run the flask app that interact with the db - so I don't get why know there are user permission problems.

The app is also owned by www-data group.

I looked at:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/k2c6PgV6WFE

**Could you please show a good procedure (ubuntu commands) to debug and correct permissions the user that is running neo4j and the permissions to db folder? should I change to root?**

my app permissions are set as :

```
/var/www/app/
testuser:www-data
```

py2neo and connectors are in

```
/var/www/app/virtualenvironment/ ..
```

and

```
/usr/share/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db
testuser:staff
```

Comment: Could it be that you started a second instance of neo4j?

Comment: I can see only one:
`ps aux | grep neo4j`
`root      4625  0.0  0.0  12916   932 pts/1    S+   15:28   0:00 grep --color=auto neo4j`

`curl localhost:7474
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 7474: Connection refused`
Yesterday was working ok, cannot figure out what happened..

Comment: Also killed  uwsgi instances listening to 7474  `lsof -Pn -i :7474` - cannot listen to 7474 anymore .

Comment: @user305883 Did you manage to fix it? I have exactly the same problem :(

Comment: @oski86 I had fixed but could not figure out what was the culprit! I "tampered" around tried moving db on another folder, kill processes, restart.

Comment: @user305883 I managed to fix this, I had the exactly same exception, but after dumping and then restoring the database. The solution was to do `chown -r neo4j` on the graph.db files.